# Scala Spark not returning value outside loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using `Apache Spark` to extract the top 10 movies and genres from `movie lens` dataset. I was able to extract the ratings but the genres for each movies are in this format `Action|War|Crime`. I split the string using `|` and try to insert it inside `ArrayBuffer` or `ListBuffer`. It works fine inside the loop but as i tried to extract these outside the loop i get empty result.

```
    val rating_data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("data/ratings.csv")

//read movie name file
val movie_name = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("data/movies.csv")

//query for movie with rating 5, matching movie id in both csv files and extract the top 10 movies with highest count of 5
 val movie_id = rating_data.filter(rating_data("rating").===(5)).groupBy("movieId").count().orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc).take(10)

var genre_list = Array[String]()
 movie_id.foreach(a => {
 #match the movies id in ratings and movie file
 val mv = movie_name.filter(movie_name("movieId").===(a(0)))

 mv.foreach(b => { 

 genre_list = b(2).toString.split('|').map(_.trim)
    genre_list.foreach(g => {
    mylist += g
    #mylist not empty , has elements 

      })
})
})
    println(mylist)  #empty
}
```

Comment: Look at the related question regarding iterating over a spark RDD and writing to a mutable collection (you cannot do that)

Comment: so now i've a confusion , how can i generate a new immutable list on every iteration ?

Comment: so now i've a confusion , how can i generate a new immutable list on every iteration ? I'm basically new over scala and spark in general, so any help would he highly appreciated

Comment: You need to solve this functionally using a map/reduce like approach.